# Spare Matrix Function

Tags: c

(Write a C function that should check if a matrix (4x5) is sparse or not. Knowing that: sparse matrix is a matrix that has zeros more than the half of its size.)

That's a problem for a sheet in out subject 
here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Spare(int [4][5]);

int main()
{
    int arr[4][5];
    int m,n;
    for(m=0;m<4;m++){
        for(n=0;n<5;n++){
            scanf("%d ",&arr[4][5]);
        }
    }
    Spare(arr[4][5]);
    return 0;
}

int Spare(int Arr[4][5]){

    int i,j;
    int zerocount=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){

            if(Arr[i][j]==0){
                zerocount++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(zerocount>=10) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Its Running but after the user enter inputs of array it stops working!
Any Help Guys?

Comment: `Spare(arr[4][5]);` ==> `Spare(arr);`, `scanf("%d ",&arr[4][5])` ==> `scanf("%d ",&arr[m][n])`

Comment: `scanf("%d ",&arr[4][5]);` is wrong. You want `scanf("%d ",&arr[m][n]);`

Comment: Spare or spar**s**e? Please fix your code and the title!

Comment: And compile with warnings enabled!

Comment: @WhozCraig Your edits are right and resolved the running problem but the new problem is that the result of function 0 for all cases of inputs

Comment: @IbrahimYamani and you know this, (always returning zero) *how* ? This code doesn't report *anything*. [See it live](http://ideone.com/z6pnE2).

Comment: @WhozCraig I ran it on codeblocks and it is giving me zero always although I saw it alive and it is working well .. it is so strange

Comment: Codeblocks was probably reporting the exit code from `main()`. Not going to sugarcoat it. [Get a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @WhozCraig I Used Your printf solution with the function and it worked 
Thanks you Bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `scanf("%d",&arr[4][5])` into `scanf("%d",&arr[m][n])`. You are just storing the input in `arr[4][5]` everytime in the loop.

The `Spare(arr[4][5])` pass the element of fifth row and sixth column only which doesn't exist.
The `Spare` function expects an array as parameter  and you are passing the single element only.
The function call must be done in this way: `Spare(arr)`

Comment: what about `Spare(arr[4][5]);` call: this is incorrect too.